# The definite article usage with objects that have names

Tags: articles, definite-articles

For example, I have a database and several tables in it. One of the tables is named Clients for this example.
When I speak about a table and need to mention its name do I have to use the definite article?

> Insert a record into the Clients table.

or

> Insert a record into Clients table.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with either

> Insert a record into the Clients table.

or

> Insert a record into Clients.

In most of my professional writing I would prefer the first option, although the second may be better in some cases for style reasons.

"Insert a record into Clients table" would not be correct, because "Clients" is a modifier to the subject "table" in this sentence, and not a proper noun.

Answer (score 2):

You would say:

> Insert a record into the *Clients* table.

This is equivalent to

> Insert a record into the table named *Clients*.

If it was unambiguous from the context that you meant the table, you could say

> Insert a record into *Clients*.